# Obj-C ARC: How to remove an object from an array/set and then return it as an autoreleased object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

How do I rewrite this method for ARC?

```
- (KTThumbView *)dequeueReusableThumbView
{
    KTThumbView *thumbView = [reusableThumbViews_ anyObject];
    if (thumbView != nil) {
        // The only object retaining the view is the
        // reusableThumbViews set, so we retain/autorelease
        // it before returning it so that it's not immediately
        // deallocated when removed form the set.
        [[thumbView retain] autorelease];
        [reusableThumbViews_ removeObject:thumbView];
    }
    return thumbView;
}
```

The automatic ARC migrator gives me this error:

```
[rewriter] it is not safe to remove an unused 'autorelease' message; its receiver may be destroyed immediately
```

Comment: chdck this link http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.retained_returns

Comment: ARC will take care of the `thumbView` by adding `autorelease` if required. you just have to leave it as is. simply return `thumbView`. Its was a bit uneasy for mr to leave my variables this way. but I can rely on ARC ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `[[thumbView retain] autorelease];` line. The first line will make a strong reference guaranteeing its around as needed.